# Adsense Placement In Game Question

Tags: google-adsense

As pertinent to here: google.com/adsense/answer/2768340?hl=en I need to have atleast 150 pixels between the game and an ad.

When a user joins or creates a game, it looks like this: http://i.gyazo.com/56ecd3d05381f3394979872a80bc1314.png

But, when you're not in-game you're at the waiting screen where you can view and find games or enter the chat (lobby room) like so: http://i.gyazo.com/9764fd83a5220000ced013a5b4531f85.png

My question is.. Adsense is not well received for chat rooms.. But that chat room is technically integrated inside my game... So will that be okay? Or how should I go about this dilemma?

Comment: Possibly. Is the content in the chat being filtered? Adsense bots look at the webpage text to determine the ad to show on the screen.

Comment: Filtered? Nope, moderated though ofc. And you have to be logged in to view the chat (Websockets), hmm... Not a good idea then?  Only display the ad on the forum section I'm assuming?

Comment: The point is adsense evaluates content, meaning text. Forums and chat sites allow users to enter content, and if you don't add a system that stops posts with bad content from being processed and you have adsense on that site, then you may be in trouble. Imagine a user randomly typing in adult keywords for a post (that google would never accept).

Comment: Oh, that makes sense @Mike. I could incorporate a serverside filter system in nodejs though to filter out all bad words / URLs / and whatnot.  Think that would be okay / enough?

Comment: (For the chat system ofc) and have moderators delete bad content as well. But, bots cannot see the chat system unless authenticated in through websockets with an account :P Hmm...

Comment: and if you block bots from adsense code behind a login by not providing them with the correct username and password, then you will not likely be credited for those ads.

Answer (score 1):

Google is extremely closed minded on this topic. Google's assessment of whether a page is a chat room or not is if there is the capacity for user chat within the page or not. I haven't been able to find the exact definition Google uses for defining a chat room but it seems to be based on any real time interactive messaging between users of a site. So a chat room, chat box, shoutbox, etc would be classified as a chat room but a user supplied comments block on the actual page content wouldn't be.

The best way in your example not to run afoul of the Google AdSense terms is to not embed the ad within the page when the chat room is showing and to only show it when the game is displayed instead.